# Why matlab code gives different result in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, rounding

So i am trying to convert this matlab code to python code on generating some pseudorandom number sequence. But the result i get from matlab code and python code at first gives slight difference until at quite some time(ex:at the 500th sequence) it really differs too much. How can i get the exact same number as i get in the matlab code?

I kinda get the problem is related to rounding difference in matlab and python. whereas at matlab it seems to round it to nearest 4 number behind decimal, and python is round it at more length. I've tried to round every operation at the pseudorandom number sequence with round(a,4) but it just makes it more differ. Help me please what did i do wrong?

Here's the matlab code

```matlab
x=0.21;
u=0.399;
d=43;     
N0=500;  
L= N0+256;
xx=zeros(1,L);
for i=1:L  
    if x<0.5
       x=(4-u)/4*sin(pi*x)+u/2*x;
    else
       x=(4-u)/4*sin(pi*x)+u/2*(1-x); 
    end
    xx(i)=x;
end
```

Here's the python code

```py
import numpy as np
def stmap(u,x,n):
    seq=[]
    for i in range(n):        
        if x<0.5:
            st=(4-u)/4*np.sin(np.pi*x)+u/2*x
        else:
            st=(4-u)/4*np.sin(np.pi*x)+u/2*(1-x)
        seq.append(st)
        x=seq[i]
    return seq
d=43
n=500
x=0.21
u=0.399
X=stmap(u,x,n+256)
```

I expect to get the exact same result with sequence i get from the matlab code.

Comment: MATLAB doesn’t round results to 4 digits. It only displays 4 digits but doesn’t change the actual values. Your problem is that you’ve got a process that is very sensitive to small disturbances, and a different order of operations, or a different rounding in the `sin` operation, will cause large changes over time.

Comment: so the problem is that the sin operation rounding at python side is different with the sin operation rounding at matlab side?

Comment: That could be one explanation. It could simply be a different order of computation of your expression.

Comment: Looks like you have the same [surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) as Edward Lorentz in 1961.